# Enzyme: How to test a wrapped form?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

So, I can't seem to find a way to do this properly. Just want to test clicking a button inside of an antd form:

```
import React...
import { shallow }...
import { SignInForm }...
import { Form } from "antd"

test("should call newFunction on button click", () => {
  const newFunction = jest.fn();
  const WrappedForm = Form.create()(SignInForm);
  const wrapper = shallow(<WrappedForm newFunction={newFunction} />);
  wrapper.find("#button-id").simulate("click");
  expect(newFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFieldDecorator' of undefined
});
```

Any thoughts on how to do this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `mount` instead of `shallow` ? If you get the same error, your problem might be in `SignInForm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the above code to work I had to:

- `yarn add jsdom jsdom-global --dev`
- Add `import "jsdom-global/register";` to the top of the test file... above `import React`...
- Change `shallow()` to `mount()`
- Export the `<WrappedForm />` from the component file instead of `const WrappedForm = Form.create()(SignInForm);` though both work

Working code:

```
test("should call newFunction on Sign In with Button click", () => {
  const newFunction = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = mount(
    <WrappedSignInForm newFunction={newFunction} />
  );
 wrapper
 .find("#button-id")
 .at(0)
 .simulate("click");
  expect(newFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```